# FCM Messaging to all registered devices

Tags: laravel, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a system build with laravel. In this system, fcm_tokens are stored on logged in. So it the user logs in to new device new fcm_token would be saved. Now while sending notifications, I am sending by fetching all the tokens from the database, and with the chunks of 1000 data, I am passing it to registration_ids.
Till now there are no topics created so, is there any way to send a notification to all registered devices.
When I send the notification using Admin SDK it goes to all devices. So is there a way to send a notification to all devices just as similar to that of Admin SDK from the backend like are there any default topics to which every devices are subscribed or by using any conditions?

Answer (score 0):

> are there any default topics to which every devices are subscribed or by using any conditions?

No, there are no default topics.  You will have to write client code to subscribe to a topic that you define.  Each client app will need to do this.  You can then use that topic to broadcast a message to all subscribing apps.

Also consider [device group messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/device-group) if you want to manage the broadcast on your backend, using device tokens received from the client apps.